# 2 Select options Combine values and link

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, location-href

I need to combine two values and link to the selected site.

ex. `select> Google> select>Translate`

join two values

```
T2 [translate] T1 [.google.com] = translate.google.com Go
```

**JS**

```
<script>
function goToNewPage() {
  var g=document.getElementById('target').value;
  {
    window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value;
  } 
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="dropdown">                    
   <select name="selected" id="target2" >
      <option selected>Select...</option>
      <option value=".google.com/">Google</option>
      <option value=".search.com/">Bing</option>
   </select>

   <select name="selected" id="target" >
      <option selected>Select...</option>
      <option value="http://translate">Translate</option>
      <option value="http://translate/">Translator</option>
   </select>
   <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.selected)">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?
How about.. window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value + document.getElementById('target2').value

Comment: Okay, added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value + document.getElementById('target2').value
```

Comment: it's been 7 minutes. time's up :P