# Option values in dropdown select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have **two drop down select** tags in one page.

The **first dropdown** box is called "states" and based off of what state is chosen...

The **second dropdown** will show the colleges in that state by having the same "VALUE"

What I am trying to do is to have a link based off of the college chosen:

- is it possible to create another value to have a link for the college chosen? or is there another way to have create a link?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for after dynamically showing colleges based on states selected. Also create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or  paste code here, to get your solution.

Comment: Perhaps you meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483631/2-select-options-combine-values-and-link or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581661/multiple-select-box-and-send-values-as-url-parameteres

Comment: You want a yes/no answer? or solution too in that case you need to include what you have tried and what problem you facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use a data attribute i.e.

```
<select class="colleges">
  <option data-link="www.colege1.com" value="state1">College 1</option>
  <option data-link="www.colege2.com" value="state1">College 2</option>
</select>

$( ".colleges" ).change(function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).find(':selected').attr("data-link"); 
 });
```

Or

```
$(this).find(':selected').data('link');
```

Would get the same attribute.

The data-* attribute gives you the ability to embed custom data attributes on any HTML elements

Comment: @mplungjan - `attr("data-link")` has the same effect as `.data("link")` *in this case,* but they're not the same: `.data()` tries to be smart about converting the type of the returned value (which won't matter for the strings in this case), and of course if you use them to *set* values the effect is different.

Comment: @mplungjan - No it isn't. When you set values with `.data()` it does *not* store them as html attributes on the element, and it can store *any* data types (including objects), not just strings.

Comment: @mplungjan I was wondering if one of you guys know about tagging system? It would be easier for me to use one instead of me making a link for every college that I have on my site. But I do not know much about PHP and MYSQL was hoping for some help

Comment: @nnnnnn - I see. That is not obvious: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/exy2g7o2/

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/o4tzx3bg/2/)

**HTML**

```
<select id="stateSelect" size="1" onchange="makeSubmenu(this.value)">
    <option selected disabled>Select State</option>
    <option value="California">California</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
</select>
<select id="collegeSelect">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select College</option>
</select>
```

**JS/JQuery**

```
    var collegeByState = {
    California: ["University of California - Irvine", "University of California - Berkeley"],
    Georgia: ["University Of Georgia", "Georgia Institute of Technology"]
}

function makeSubmenu(state)
{
    var collegeOpt = "";
    collegeOpt += "<option selected disabled>Select College</option>";
    for (collegeId in collegeByState[state]) 
    {
        collegeOpt += "<option value='" + collegeByState[state][collegeId] + "'>" + collegeByState[state][collegeId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("collegeSelect").innerHTML = collegeOpt;
}
```

**Note :** The values you give for first select(drop-down) should be exactly same for the array.

Here for example: value="California" so in array California:["option1","option2"]

Comment: Thanks!! I had this part running a different way that dealt with more coding .