# make a select dependent with js

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to do a select option dependent of another select, i saw there's a way using array with fixed values, but my array is reloaded every time we add a new form field on the form. I would like something like when i select op1, then it just show op1 options on second select.

```html
<select id="id1" name="optionshere">
     <option relone="op1">opt one</option>
     <option relone="op2">opt two</option>
</select>

<select id="id2" name="resulthere">
    <option relone="op1">ans 1 op1</option>
    <option relone="op1">ans 2 op2</option>
    <option relone="op2">ans 1 op2</option>
</select>
```

Any idea?

thanks all

Comment: What's your JavaScript?

Comment: Did you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085318/option-values-in-dropdown-select-tag/31092227#31092227

Comment: @Rafael The link i provided was that helpful? Or do you need something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method without jQuery:

When you select an option in the first selectbox, it will hide everything that doesn't match its relone.

```js
var id1 = document.getElementById("id1");
var id2 = document.getElementById("id2");

id1.addEventListener("change", change);

function change() {
  for (var i = 0; i < id2.options.length; i++)
    id2.options[i].style.display = id2.options[i].getAttribute("relone") == id1.options[id1.selectedIndex].getAttribute("relone") ? "block" : "none";
  id2.value = "";
}

change();
```

```html
<select id="id1" name="optionshere">
  <option relone="op1">opt one</option>
  <option relone="op2">opt two</option>
</select>

<select id="id2" name="resulthere">
  <option relone="op1">ans 1 op1</option>
  <option relone="op1">ans 2 op1</option>
  <option relone="op2">ans 1 op2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If Jquery is an option you may go with something like this:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $('#id1').change(function() {
            var x = $(this).val();
            $('option[relone!=x]').each(function() {
               $(this).hide();
            });
            $('option[relone=x]').each(function() {
               $(this).show();
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Then to expand:
There really are many ways in which you can solve this predicament, depending on how variable your pool of answers is going to be.

If you're only interested in using vanilla javascript then let's start with the basics. You're going to want to look into the "onchange" event for your html, so as such:

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">
```

Coming right out of the w3schools website, on the Html onchange event attribute:

> The onchange attribute fires the moment when the value of the element
>   is changed.

This will allow you to make a decision based on this element's value. Then inside your js may branch out from here:

1. You may use **Ajax** and pass to it that value as a get variable to obtain those options from a separate file.
2. You may get all options from the second div through a combination of `.getElementbyId("id2")` and `.getElementsByTagName("option")` then check for their individual "relone" attribute inside an each loop, and hide those that don't match, and show those that do.

Really, it's all up to what you want to do from there, but I personally would just go for the Jquery approach